# Transpose Datatable then Sort by Rows... Possible?

Tags: c#

I have a datatable and after transposing it I'm wanting to allow the end user to sort by the old columns that are now rows. Is it possible for the end user to select a specific row and sort it asc or desc, in the same fashion as sorting a column? TIA

Note: These are example tables

[image]

Comment: it sounds like you might need to change your view rather than change the table.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep a reference to the original data table (if asp.net, in `Session`, for example) and when the row is clicked, you map it to the original column, sort the original DataTable, retranspose it and rebind it.

Comment: @BlakeAdams you are right. I had missed the point. I thought the user wanted to sort the transposed table by columns. I've amended my answer.

Comment: That would be going through quite a lot of work, even though the coding of it would be quick, it would be terribly inefficient.  If the tables will always be of a size similar to the example, then sure, but if they grow much that just wouldn't scale all that well.